# How to build a docker image for tensorflow?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I took part in an online challenge recently where all participants are asked to **submit models in the form of a docker image** so that the organizers can run them and reproduce results. Although I've googled key words incorporated docker and tensorflow, I didn't find satisfying results. As I'm new to docker, so can anybody teach me **how to build a docker image for tensorflow and python**. I'm using tensorflow in python with jupyter notebook on windows10. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are several public docker images on docker hub. You can look at those projects as a start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to set this up in some base system (say a linux system), you can easily containerize it with Dockerfile's.

Lots of pages can help you write one, For starters follow,

[Dockerfile formation - Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-using-dockerfiles-to-automate-building-of-images)

Comment: Thank a lot! Your advice helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Docker search result sorted based on stars

https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=tensorflow&starCount=1

Apparently, this is the official repo

https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/

## Edit

Here is the Dockefile link https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/tools.Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks a lot! But actually, I don't want to use an off-the-shelf image or container. What I really want to know is how to write a dockerfile that can build an image able to run my .ipynb file.

Comment: Take look at the official Dockerfile of Tensorflow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile and see whether this make any sense or not